# Why does IMU acceleration bias increase with increase in acceleration?

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, bias, imu, navigation

I am trying to estimate the wheel speed scale factor of a vehicle. I find that whenever the vehicle accelerates rapidly,the estimated speed is lower than the true speed. In other words, I see bias in my estimation. This bias most probably comes from incorrect speed scale factor estimation.
Can anyone explain why the scale factor error increases with increase in acceleration.
Is there any way to estimate or minimize this error at high acceleration?

Comment: And when you decelerate the wheel is the bias negative?

Comment: During deceleration, I dont see negative bias consistently, but only sometimes.

Comment: It's beginning to sound like an error due to sampling delay.

Comment: What happens when the wheel is at a constant RPM?  Is the speed estimate still lower than the actual speed?